# Selenium 3.5.0 with old version

Tags: python, selenium

I'm quite a newbie on selenium.

I'm working with selenium in Python and today I upgraded to selenium 3.5.0 with pip. Everything went well (see image).

[image]

But if I try to ask the selenium version I got a different version (3.4.3):

[image]

What can be the reason? I tried also to uninstall (successfully) and reinstall (successfully). But the version is still wrong.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have Python 2 and Python 3 in your systems?

Comment: No, only Python 3.6.1

Answer (score 0):

In **`Python 3.6.1`**:

1. To see the version of **`Selenium`** installed:

   ```
   pip show -V selenium
   ```
2. To upgrade the version of **`Selenium`** to the latest version:

   ```
   pip install -U selenium
   ```
3. To uninstall **`Selenium`** completely:

   ```
   pip uninstall selenium
   ```
4. To install **`Selenium`** of a particular version:

   ```
   pip install selenium==3.5.0
   ```
5. To upgrade the version of **`Selenium`** to a specific version:

   ```
   pip install -U selenium==3.5.0
   ```